# REGEX matches with 100% confidence, what about 99%?

Tags: ruby, regex, machine-learning

in my app a user is able to enter text, which later I then search from and extract based on future submission.

Problem is users can sometimes have a type or forget a period, etc...

is there a way in ruby to say match with X% confidence level?

Meaning if the match goal is 500 characters, and a match was found with 490 characters, match it, versus not matching anything?

Thanks

Comment: Typically, regex matches exactly what it's told to match.  You can change the criteria, but you can't follow up on partial matches ... unless someone's cleverly written their own regex engine to so do.  I wait for someone to tell me that's the case and post a link with great interest :P

Comment: Regex are not fuzzy. They match or they don't match, there is no "almost match". [Fuzzy searches](http://www.google.com/search?q=ruby+%2B+%22fuzzy+search%22) exist but I haven't played with any in Ruby.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this case, regular expressions aren't your best tool.  Maybe something like [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) instead?

Answer (score 6):

I read about the Tre library recently, sounds like what you are looking for:

http://laurikari.net/tre/

Answer (score 5):

I would look into: [TRE - The free and portable approximate regex matching library](http://laurikari.net/tre/).

Answer (score 3):

Adding to the string distance tools: amatch http://flori.github.com/amatch/  This has several string distance algorithms and they are written in C.  It is very fast.